# Android Index out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Some how my index keeps going out of bounds. I know I have there elements in my content arrays. And I loop through this content 3 times each time adding the indexed element. Why am I still getting this error. Please help. Thank you all in advance

```
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gordondev.tlchackprep/com.gordondev.tlchackprep._App}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.gordondev.tlchackprep.SimpleAdapter.<init>(SimpleAdapter.java:66)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.gordondev.tlchackprep._App$PinnedListView.initializeAdapter(_App.java:280)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.gordondev.tlchackprep._App$PinnedListView.initializeHeaderAndFooter(_App.java:262)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at com.gordondev.tlchackprep._App$PinnedListView.onActivityCreated(_App.java:168)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1707)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:907)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1443)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5142)
03-19 09:53:06.041: E/AndroidRuntime(14937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239)
```

Here is my code. 
Line of error:  **Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, content[index]);**

```
String[] title = { "Scope of this Chapter", "Penalties" };

    String[] content = {
            "Other than words that are capitalized in the normal course "
                    + "(such as “Mayor of the City of New York” or the first word in a sentence) "
                    + "any word (or group of words) in these Rules that has its first letter capitalized will be a “defined term.”",
            "\nMost defined terms appear in this Chapter. For ease of reference, certain defined terms may also appear in the"
                    + " “Definitions Applicable to this Chapter” section of Chapters in which the terms are most relevant. "
                    + "Certain general terms (Driver, License, Owner, for example) will have a more specific meaning in individual "
                    + "Chapters (so, Driver in the Chapters governing Taxicabs and their Drivers will mean a Taxicab Driver). In some "
                    + "cases, a defined term in a Chapter can have a meaning different from that in this Chapter (for example, a Broker "
                    + "in Chapter 65 is different). Those different definitions will appear in the relevant Chapters.",
            "This Chapter is informational in nature and does not contain penalties" };

    final int sectionsNumber = title.length;
    final int arrayIter[] = { 2, 1 };
    int index = 0;
    int check = 0;
    int j;
    int k;

    prepareSections(sectionsNumber);
    int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sectionsNumber; i++) {
        Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, title[i]);
        section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
        section.listPosition = listPosition++;
        onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
        add(section);

        for (j = 0; j < arrayIter.length; j++) {
            check = arrayIter[j];

            for (k = 1; k <= check; k++) {
                Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, content[index]);
                item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                add(item);
                index++;
            }
        }

        sectionPosition++;

    }
```

Comment: So `content` is an array of exactly one string? Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: You're incrementing `index` lots of times, and never resetting it... are you sure you meant to do that?

Comment: There are three Strings in content array.

Comment: Yes because I want to keep the index so the next time through the loop it adds from the last place in the content array. I want it to keep track.

Comment: As soon as `index` goes beyond 2 you will get the error.

Comment: My bad, I didn't scroll over. The problem is as @JonSkeet says, you're incrementing `index` too far. The first time through the inner-most loop, `index` increments up to `2`. The next time through it increments to `3` and you're out of bounds.

Comment: The inner most look will go at least three times. The first time it has index of zero because of value set outside look. Then next time 1 and then two? I am still confused how I am going out of bounds. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Justin Jasmann is correct.  You are using the variable "index" to index the array "content". "index" is incremented arrayIter.length * check times (the number of times through the inner loop time the number of times through the outer loop).   That number is way bigger than the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the situation by this condition...

```
if(index < content.length())
    Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, content[index]);
    item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
    item.listPosition = listPosition++;
    add(item);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: I need the loop to go around three times in two different settings. The first time twice. And the then the second time once. Each time keeping place of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `index = 0`  before the `for (k = 1; k <= check; k++)` loop; if not the next time that enters in that loop index will give you problems

Comment: This gets of my error, but I need the inner most loop to keep the indexed element after the first initial run. Your solution restarts the content array back from the first element. I want the inner most loop to run 3 times. First twice and then once. Each time keeping track of the index on content array.

Comment: And will work if you initizize `index` before the `for (j = 0; j < arrayIter.length; j++)` loop?

Comment: When I do as you mentioned I get a result that doesnt achieve what I was trying to do. I have an array for 3 Strings. I want the for loop to iterate twice the first time taking the first two index string and adding them to a specific location. Then one more adding the last string to different location. What I get when I use that code is  all three strings being added to both locations.

Comment: could you post the expected results? i really do not understand your code and what try to achieve